# TYPO3: Not be able to copy content to a new language

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 as the CMS for a customer website.
Currently the company is expanding to the US so the website should be available in English as well. I've added a news language (en) in TYPO3 and configured it. Everything works quite fine but it's only possible to translate the content, not to copy it.

[image]

Caused by this it's not possible to add some content to the English version which is not available in german.

I'm using version 8.7.8.

Comment: are you added language configuration?

Comment: Sure. In the template file...

Comment: You really should disguise the emails and names of your client in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can only choose to Translate or Copy if there is not already some content in the language. When you have already copied a single element, you can only copy the other content.

If you have already translated an element, you can only translate the other elements.

Thats made so translated and copied content does not get mixed.
Its theoretically still possible if you edit an element and select the language there = translated. When you then remove the relation its considered a copy.
You will however get a warning in the backend that your content is mixed with copies and translations.